# Where is this possibly WWI Eastern European military uniform from?

Tags: military, identification, uniform

This family members picture is a mystery. I would like to be able to know what country and military unit this uniform is from. I think is is eastern Europe around World war 1 era.[image: Family Member in Uniform]

Comment: Hello & thanks for the question! Is there any writing of any kind on the photo?

Comment: Additionally: Would it be possible to take the picture out of the frame and onto a scanner, to give as high(er) resolution image? Of special interest are the areas: hat, belt, collar, cuffs, button-line, shoulders, perhaps even shoes and sidearm.

Comment: Provide a full visual description for the blind and search engines.

Comment: Austro-Hungarian definitely, but since they had many "separate" armies it is hard to tell which part https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Armed_Forces

Answer (score 2):

Based on a these links: [1](https://i.pinimg.com/736x/54/be/04/54be04595a834514ade6d97ec10ed49a--military-uniforms-austro-hungarian.jpg),[2](https://www.pinterest.com/daveolinyk/ww1-austro-hungarian-army-uniforms/), an [3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austro-Hungarian_Army#/media/File:BASA-1221K-1-48-11.jpg) your relative is wearing an Austro-Hungarian uniform, probably Austrian (according to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YLy7UCRjkc)). More detail on the photo would possibly allow for a better ID.

Comment: Thank you so very much for the insight. This makes sense to me. Gary